# mysql, merge data of two columns into one

Tags: mysql

i have a table like this

```
id    genre    genre2
1      25        0
2      12        25
3      25        12
4      18        17
5      19        14
```

and i want to count the different genres id and the count of them in both columns but merged into one

and want a result like this

```
genre    count
25         3
12         2
18         1
19         1
17         1
14         1
0          1
```

i have tried unions, and counts, and everything i think of, but i cant achieve to get the result i want, the closest was making two querys and UNION them, but it doesnt work like i want

any ideas?  thanks  for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use `UNION ALL` instead `UNION`.

```
SELECT
genre, COUNT(*) cnt
FROM
(SELECT genre FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT genre2 FROM tbl) a
GROUP BY genre
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

You can try it on **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31137/5)**